# how to get bitbucket tagged commits sorted by weekly using Bitbucket API?

Tags: git, bitbucket, bitbucket-api

I am working on a project that needs to fetch all tagged commits sorted by weekly datetime. I first tried using this API /2.0/repositories/{workspace}/{slug}/commits?sort=-target.date but the results are fetched all data.

I can have the expected results by writing some code but can we get same through bitbucket API ?